# ERROR: modpost: "mem_map" undefined! with minimal config, but error is gone with default config. Why?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Recently I tried to build a linux device driver for kernel 5.10.0-rc5, I met with compile error below.

```
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/Proj/QEMU/qemu_test/test_ldd_5100$ make
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-none-linux-gnu- -C linux-5.10.0-rc5 M=/home/ckim/Proj/QEMU/qemu_test/test_ldd_5100 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ckim/Proj/QEMU/qemu_test/test_ldd_5100/linux-5.10.0-rc5'
  MODPOST /home/ckim/Proj/QEMU/qemu_test/test_ldd_5100/Module.symvers
ERROR: modpost: "mem_map" [/home/ckim/Proj/QEMU/qemu_test/test_ldd_5100/axpu_ldd_kc.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "kmem_cache_alloc_trace" [/home/ckim/Proj/QEMU/qemu_test/test_ldd_5100/axpu_ldd_kc.ko] undefined!
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:111: /home/ckim/Proj/QEMU/qemu_test/test_ldd_5100/Module.symvers] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/home/ckim/Proj/QEMU/qemu_test/test_ldd_5100/Module.symvers'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1703: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ckim/Proj/QEMU/qemu_test/test_ldd_5100/linux-5.10.0-rc5'
make: *** [Makefile:19: all] Error 2
```

and I realized I've built the kernel previously using very minimal config for my board. So I switched to defconfig and built the kernel again and now the error is gone. When I used a minimal config, how are those kinds of errors coming? and How can I find what CONFIGs should I add to solve the compile error?

Comment: Normally, Linux kernel doesn't *declare* symbols (in the header) if that symbols are not defined in the code in given configuration. So instead of the *linker* error about undefined symbols you should get a *compiler* error. Please, show your code. It smells like **your code** defines some `CONFIG_*` macros for get access to the needed functions. None code should do that.

Comment: "How can I find what CONFIGs should I add to solve the compile error?" - Find definition of the symbol in the source code, and find which `CONFIG_*` macros guards it (via `ifdef`). Also take into account that some source files are compiled only when some configurations options are enabled. You could find this information by inspecting `Makefile` which builds given sources. E.g. `mem_map` variable is declared here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.111/source/mm/memory.c#L98 and `kmem_cache_alloc_trace` function here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.111/source/mm/slab.c#L3545.

Comment: Strange. `mem_map` should be both present and exported unless `CONFIG_NEED_MULTIPLE_NODES` is enabled, which doesn't sound like a minimal config.